# Element destroyed out of set parameters due to script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I have a script in Unity that destroys an object once it falls below 0 on the Y-axis. It seems to be destroying itself even though it is above 100 on Y.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class FallBeneathZero : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y < 0f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

On Unity Answers, it says there is an extra semicolon somewhere. This does not seem to be the case. Could someone confirm or deny this, or maybe even fix whatever is wrong with my script? Thank you!

Comment: Well you say it is above 100 on Y but how am I supposed to be sure of that from the details given? Another possibility may be that it's position is being set somewhere so that it starts below 0. We need more information. Yet another possibility is that game object is disabled. Did you verify the GameObject does not appear in the hierarchy?

Comment: For the particular code you display there is no issues. The first place I would start either way is to enable the debugger and place a break point on *Object.Destroy(gameObject);* let me know if it actually lands. If it does, check the coordinates of the transform position.

Comment: Omar, I was just explaining that the GameObject is supposed to destroy itself when falling below 0 but it's far from there. The object is supposed to be in the hierarchy, by the way.

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstood my comment, I meant in general did you verify that the game object appears in the hierarchy in the first place. That was not intended to be related to it being enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [`Destroy()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) the gameObject that the script lies upon you would need to just call `Destroy(gameObject)` instead of `Object.Destroy(gameObject);`

**Example:**

```cs
if (transform.position.y < 0f)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will definitely incorporate that into my script. My issue, though, is that the GameObject using this script keeps destroying itself when uncalled for. The Object is supposed to be destroyed when it is below zero on the y-axis, but it disappears when it hits 100. Could you help with this?

Comment: I incorporated my entire script in my question. There is only one instance of Destroy(gameobject).

Comment: That's odd. What I mean destroyed, I mean disappearing off the hierarchy and being removed from the scene. This is only supposed to happen when the GameObject falls below 0 on the y-axis, but it disappears at 100. I'm not getting any error messages, that's just what happens.

Comment: Alright, I think I may have found the source of my problem. I moved the GameObject up to 1000 just so it wouldn't be so close to 0. When play is hit, The y-axis' value will rapidly decrease even though the actual game object (in-game view) hasn't moved. I also checked the ground, it's not moving. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If the GameObject was falling, the ground and player would be also. I still see the GameObject in GameView, but  the player's y-axis value remains the same as the GameObject's value somehow decreases.

Comment: Oh well!! I appreciate your help. I might try Unity Answers, but this site is a ton more helpful. Doubt anyone will come by this question again; my questions are apparently so silly they just have to be downvoted.

Comment: Oh. I'll try to work on clarity, but at the time I thought my problem was with the script.

Comment: Not trying to be aggressive but it's clear to many proficient Unity developers that your script is perfectly fine. So naturally when we see *It seems to be destroying itself even though it is above 100 on Y.* we know that can't be the case. It would just be advisable to do some debugging on your own before asking the question because even you recognized that Y was below 0 when it was destroyed and that could have easily been spotted by debugging beforehand.